# how to remove error "passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_entry_get_buffer’ from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am new to GTK and GALDE. I am making a normal GUI in which I have one start button and one update button, so that if I click on start button, start should be displayed in text entry and same for the update button.I am using text entry and its buffer for start and update. Everything is running fine but I am getting warning

`passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_entry_get_buffer’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`    and

`assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

Please help in removing these errors.!

Below is the code which I am using

`GtkBuilder *builder;`

`GtkWidget  *main_window;`

`GtkWidget  *start_button;`

`GtkWidget  *update_button;`

`GtkWidget  *start_entry;`

`GtkWidget  *update_entry;`

`GtkWidget  *start_entry_buffer;`

`GtkWidget  *update_entry_buffer;`

```
void on_start_button_clicked(GtkButton *start_button)
{

    gtk_entry_buffer_set_text (start_entry_buffer,"start ",-1); //error
}


void on_update_button_clicked(GtkButton *update_button)
{

    gtk_entry_buffer_set_text (update_entry_buffer,"update ",-1);//error
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if(gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "example.glade", NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error Glade File not Found\n");
        exit(0);
    }


    main_window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "main_window"));
    start_button = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "start_button"));
    update_button = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "update_button"));

    start_entry  = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "start_entry"));
    start_entry_buffer = gtk_entry_get_buffer (start_entry);//error

    update_entry  = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "update_entry"));
    update_entry_buffer = gtk_entry_get_buffer (update_entry);//error


    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));
    gtk_widget_show (main_window);

            gtk_main ();

            return 0;
}
```

Thanks.!

Comment: And *where* do you get the errors? On what lines? Please edit your question to show it in the source.

Comment: And also please show variable declarations.

Comment: You have more problems to think about like, why is `builder` declared as a global variable? is it a flaw in the design? and you probably need a macro like `GTK_BUILDER` to cast the value to the correct type, But I don't know if that is the exact name of the macro, also you didn't post the declaration of `builder` which you really should remove from the global scope.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i have put //error at the line where I am getting error

Comment: @iharob the person's question has nothing to do with GtkBuilder; his use of GtkBuilder is correct. And what harm is it that the GtkBuilder is global? There's no bug there. The problem is that he didn't see that there is a `GTK_ENTRY(...)` for taking a GtkWidget and turning it into a GtkEntry, whereas he used `GTK_WIDGET(...)` to turn the GtkBuilder's GObjects into GtkWidgets.

Comment: @andlabs yes you are right.!

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the `GTK_WIDGET(...)` casts around all your `gtk_builder_get_object()` calls? It's the same idea for casting a GtkWidget to a GtkEntry: wrap your variable around a `GTK_ENTRY(...)` and it should work. There's one of these for every GTK+ and GLib type. In addition, using these function casts will give you warnings at runtime if you use the wrong variable in your cast.

Comment: it works but the error  assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  is still there.

Comment: Docs will show you that gtk_entry_get_buffer() does not return a GtkWidget at all, the error is probably referring to that.